# Connection Refused on Android Mobile Device

Tags: android, httpconnection

I am getting a strange exception while I try to hit my server api url from my mobile device.It occurs sometimes on my device and the problem goes away when I switch off and On the Wifi. Why this is so?

There are so many relevant questions and answers available on the StackOverflow regarding the same, but no one has explained the actual cause and solution to the same

However it works PERFECTLY when I hit same url on BROWSER, but it not works well on Application.

Here is my Exception:

```
07-08 09:53:27.125: W/System.err(8958): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080 refused
```

Let me know if anyone has best cause and best solution for the same. Thanks

Comment: In Which version of android? also please explain what you trying to do,means calling web-service?

Comment: yes I am calling a webservice. Version 4.4.2

Comment: Could you please post full logcat about error?